# Maximum likelihood parameter estimation for state space model (Kalman Filter)

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, matlab, kalman-filter, state-space-models

it´s about a state space model that I want to run using the Kalman filter. However, certain parameters are unknown and must be estimated by the maximum likelihood method. The state space model is as follows: Alpha evolves according to an autoregressive process. If we use the following notation we get the following system

\begin{align}
\alpha_{t+1} &=  (1-G)B+G\alpha_{t}+\phi^ix_t+v^i_{t+1} \\
R^i_{i+1}&=\beta^i_{i+1}R^M_{t+1}+\eta^i_{t+1}\\
B&=B: \text{unobserved}
\end{align}

$x_t$ is a two-dimensional vector with known stationary exogenous state variables.
If we use the following notation:

$
 \xi_t= \left(\begin{array}{c} B \\ \alpha_t \end{array}\right)$
$  \widetilde{G}= \left( \begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0  \\ 
1-G & G \\
\end{array}\right)$ $ V_{t+1}= \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ v_{t+1} \end{array}\right)$ $\Phi_{t}= \left(\begin{array}{c} 0^T \\ \phi^T \end{array}\right) $ $ H_t= \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ R^M_t \end{array}\right)$

where 0 is a vector of zeros of the same dimension as $x_t$

we get the following system

\begin{align}
\xi_{i+1}&= \widetilde{G}\xi_t+\phi x_t + V_{t+1} \\
R_{t}&= H^T\xi_t +\eta_t
\end{align}

The autoregressive parameter G, the standard deviations
of error terms $(\sigma_\eta)^2$ and $(\sigma_v)^2$, and the loadings on the conditioning variables $\phi$ should be estimated using maximum likelihood on the
whole history of portfolio returns $R_t$,the market returns $R^M_t$, and the state variables $x_t$.

I have read in books that yes there are different likelihood functions according to state space model and parameters already known. Unfortunately, I am not sure which likelihood function is the correct one. Is there a concrete function in Python/Matlab/R that provide a function or package for exactly this case to determine these parameters via ML? I know that for such a system in a paper the parameters were determined. Unfortunately, it was not discussed how to implement this concretely.

Comment: There is an R package `dlm` which has a lot of its code in pure R. For implementation, have a look at that code!